# Is there something specific for using re.search() to match multiline pattern within a function? Python

Tags: python, regex, multilinestring

I'm trying to search `r'CONTENTS\.\n+CHAPTER I\.'` within [a string from Gutenberg project](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-0.txt), but I'm getting `AttributeError`, as it doesn't match, but the same pattern does match outside the function. My code is below:

```
def gutenberg(url):
    responce=request.urlopen(url)
    raw=responce.read().decode('utf8')
    print(re.search(r"CONTENTS\.\n+CHAPTER I\.",raw).group())

a=gutenberg("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-0.txt")
```

Output:

```
...
print(re.search(r"CONTENTS\.\n+CHAPTER I\.",raw).group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

And outside the function:

```
a="""Complete









 CONTENTS.



 CHAPTER I. Civilizing"""

re.search(r"CONTENTS\.\n+CHAPTER I\.",a).group()
```

Output:

```
'CONTENTS.\n\nCHAPTER I.'
```

Though, it works fine within the function when there's no new line character in the pattern: `print(re.search(r"CONTENTS\.",raw).group())`.
So, I believe I need something like `flags`.

What I've tried:

`print(re.search(r"CONTENTS\.\n+CHAPTER I\.",raw,re.M).group())`

```
  pattern=re.compile(r'CONTENTS.\n+CHAPTER I.')
  print(pattern.search(raw).group())
```

I even tried to add a backslash into my pattern: `r"CONTENTS\.\\n+CHAPTER I\."` - the same `AttributeError`.

I read about `flags=regex.VERSION1` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257610/python-regular-expression-for-pattern-re-search) but I couldn't find information about it in [the last Python's regex guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), so I haven't tried to use it.

Any ideas how to search for multiline pattern within a function?

In general, what's confusing me much is different behavior of re.search() inside and outside the function. Is there a conception I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance! I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't something special, and it doesn't matter whether you're "in a function" or not. The data you pulled down from that URL simply doesn't match your pattern: it has `\r\n` line endings and not `\n`. Your "outside the function" test case with the literal string is testing on *different data* which does match the pattern.